# How can I plot (multiple) linear regression residual plot "for each coefficient" in R

Tags: r, regression

As a result of linear regression, we can have its residual and see its plot to check whether it shows normal distributed or not as follows :

```
library(car)
m1 <- lm(mpg~disp+hp+wt+drat, data=mtcars)  #Create a linear model
resid(m1) #List of residuals
plot(density(resid(m1))) #A density plot
qqnorm(resid(m1)) # A quantile normal plot - good for checking normality
qqline(resid(m1))
```

We can have std for each parameters, however, it seems I could not find the source to create linear regression residuals for each parameters.

residualPlots function (in car package) is fine, but it would be nice if I could have its distribution or boxplot as well.

Let me know how I can plot each parameters in R.

Comment: Does [this](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/6214_e745e9c39bdc42b095964ca64c3ae05a.html) help?

Comment: Dear Christoph, it looks pretty nice. Thank you for the sharing!